# Get Compass Heading when device is rotated in Ionic/Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, compass-geolocation

I have an Ionic/Cordova app where I need to get the direction the device is pointing to.

So I'm using the [Cordova Plugin Device Orientation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-orientation) to get the compass data. But then I need to take into account, when the user rotates his device (portrait/landscape). I use the [Cordova Plugin Screen Orientation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/reference/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/) to get the Screen-Orientation.

- When the device is in portrait mode, I use the data from the compass
- When rotated left/right (landscape) I add 90/270 degrees
- When device is upside down (portrait) I add 180 degrees
- And then I remove 360 if value > 360

But as documented in the Screen Orientation plugin this does not work on Android, when the device is upside down, or even when it's rotated from landscape through the bottom to the other landscape: "The screen.orientation property will not update when the phone is rotated 180 degrees."

So my problem is: When the device is upside or rotated around the bottom I still get "LANDSCAPE_PRIMARY" or "LANDSCAPE_SECONDARY", cause this is not supported. So I can't calculate the correct heading.

Any idea how to do this in Ionic/Cordova? I couldn't find any other plugins and I would like to avoid creating my own.

Additional information:

- On a Samsung Tablet it works correctly
- On a Samsung Phone it does not, looks like "upside down apps" are not allowed

---

Edit: I created a simple page to show the behaviour. It shows the heading directly from the compass. This value changes, when the device is rotated (portrait/landscape) and the value I try to calculate (which should stay the same, when the device is rotated).

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { DeviceOrientationCompassHeading } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/device-orientation';
import { DeviceOrientation } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/device-orientation/ngx';
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/screen-orientation/ngx';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-orientation',
    template: 'Heading: {{compassHeading}}/{{calculatedHeading}}'
})
export class OrientationPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    compassHeading: number;
    calculatedHeading: number;

    private sub: Subscription;

    constructor(private deviceOrientation: DeviceOrientation,
                private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.sub = this.deviceOrientation.watchHeading().pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe({
                next: (currentHeading: DeviceOrientationCompassHeading) =>
                {
                    this.compassHeading = currentHeading?.trueHeading;
                    this.calculatedHeading = this.calcHeading(currentHeading, this.screenOrientation);
                },
                error: (error) => console.error('Cannot subscribe to device orientation: ', error)
            }
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub?.unsubscribe();
    }

    calcHeading(currentHeading: DeviceOrientationCompassHeading, screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation): number {
        if (currentHeading?.trueHeading) {
            const rotationDelta = this.getScreenRotationDelta(screenOrientation);
            const heading = currentHeading.trueHeading + rotationDelta;

            // limit to 360
            return heading % 360;
        }

        return undefined;
    }

    getScreenRotationDelta(screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation): number {
        switch (screenOrientation.type) {
            case screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE_PRIMARY:
                return 90;
            case screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT_SECONDARY:
                // I never get this value on android phone :-(
                return 180;
            case screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE_SECONDARY:
                return 270;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic has their in house plugin that works great: [@capacitor/motion](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/motion) Why not use this instead?